# iOS/xCode7 tablecell not drawing on iPad

Tags: ios, uitableview

Having a problem with some tableviews that were rendering fine a few days ago. The table cells render properly on an iPhone and in all the simulators (including the iPad simulators). However, no data shows when run on an iPad device. I have stepped through code and I can see cellForRowAtIndexPath being executed as expected, but nothing is drawn on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

So, I will answer my own question.

Not sure how it happened but my tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method signature changed from returning CGFloat to float; changing back to CGFloat or double fixed it. Not sure how the method got changed in multiple files, but the same change fixed the tables.

Lesson for the day: pay more attention to compiler warnings